# What is the most efficient way to count how many rows in a dataframe were "active" for every minute of a day?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I have a dataframe of the format:

```
object_id  start_time  end_time
123        13:23       13:28
234        13:25       13:26
```

And I want to transform it into a format like this:

```
time    number_of_objects_active
13:22                          0
13:23                          1
13:24                          1
13:25                          2
13:26                          1
13:27                          1
13:28                          1
13:29                          0
```

Where each row has the minute of the day and the count of how many objects were active at that point (where active means time is greater than or equal to start time and less than end time).

I have tried to come up with some way of doing a groupby but have failed miserably. A not very nice solution is to loop through every minute of the day, and then sum the number of rows which were active in that minute:

```
results_dictionary = {}
for minute in minutes:
    results_dictionary[minute] = df.loc[(df.start_time <= minute) & (df.end_time > minute)].shape[0]
```

but I suspect there's a nicer more pandas/pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: In your original DataFrame, are the times stored as strings or datetime objects, or something else?

Comment: Currently they're datetime objects but not attached to that approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on pandas v0.25 or later, use `explode`:

```
# Convert `start_time` and `end_time` to Timestamp, if they
# are not already. This also allows you to adjust cases where
# the times cross the day boundary, e.g.: 23:00 - 02:00
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])
df['end_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_time'])

# Make a `time` column that holds a minutely range. We will
# later explode it into individual minutes
f = lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_time'], row['end_time'], freq='T')
df['time'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

# The reporting range, adjust as needed
t = pd.date_range('13:23', '13:30', freq='T')

result = df.explode('time') \
            .groupby('time').size() \
            .reindex(t).fillna(0) \
            .to_frame('active')
result.index = result.index.time
```

Result:

```
          active
13:23:00     1.0
13:24:00     1.0
13:25:00     2.0
13:26:00     2.0
13:27:00     1.0
13:28:00     1.0
13:29:00     0.0
13:30:00     0.0
```